# Making a flexbox div inside another flexbox div resize automatically as the browser is resized

Tags: flexbox, responsive, project, spotify

I am working on a spotify clone project and I came up with a problem, i am using flexbox to design the whole page and any inner content as well. Initially I created a #main div flexbox and inside it there are two more flexboxes namely #player and #screen as you know the player element should be of a definite height and should not change on resizing the browser and I managed to do that but when I was trying to create a #playlist-bar div inside #screen similar to that in the app and replicating its behaviour I observed that in the spotify app on resizing the window the playlist-bar adjust its height automatically to fit in (see by yourself) but when I was trying to do it is not getting the same a I want instead it makes the whole screen div scrollable and I don't want that scroll able div there. I used flex shrink property too but it doesn't help.

Can anyone help me doing it by sharing an example.

This is when the browser is in full screen

[image]

And this is when it got resized

[image]

Please share any solution if you have.